# Hide/Show not working in Chrome/Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML part

```
<select class="input-medium">
    <option id="1" value="">Select</option>
    <option id="2" value="">Date</option>
    <option id="3" value="">ID</option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="hide"  name="daterange" id="from" value="" data-modal="calendar_modal">
<input type="text" class="hide" name="daterange" id="to" value="" data-modal="calendar_modal" >
<input type="text" class="" name="" id="txt" value="">
```

Jquery part

```
$(document).off("click", "#1").on("click", "#1", function() {
    $("#from").hide();
    $("#to").hide();
});

$(document).off("click", "#2").on("click", "#2", function() {
    $("#from").show();
    $("#to").show();
    $("#txt").hide();
});

$(document).off("click", "#3").on("click", "#3", function() {
    $("#from").hide();
    $("#to").hide();
    $("#txt").show();                           
});
```

The above code works in Firefox and IE. Not working in Chrome and Safari.. How to fix this issue so that it will work on all browsers.

Comment: What is not working? What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: Whats with the .off? did you have click events bound already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Please see this fiddle: 
  **http://jsfiddle.net/948cn/1/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.input-medium').change(function () {
    var id = $(this).find('option:selected').attr("id");
    $('#from, #to, #txt').hide();

    if(id=='2'){
        $('#from, #to').show();
    }else if(id=='3')
    {
        $('#txt').show();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: MaveRick answer is best.

Comment: @user3379372 I've added a fiddle, but it does the same thing as MaveRick's answer.. If this is not functionality you need you should update the question with more details and maybe we can help you out a bit better.

Comment: Your above code works fine not MaveRick code..However, for #from and #to ids am using datepicker.When i select the date in the picker, the field gets disappear..any solution for this..

Answer (score 2):

**Edited:**

Check this out [http://jsfiddle.net/948cn/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/948cn/)

HTML:

```
<style>
.hide {
    display:none;
}
<style>
<select id="selectBox" class="input-medium">
    <option id="1" value="">Select</option>
    <option id="2" value="date">Date</option>
    <option id="3" value="txt">ID</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="inputs hide date" name="daterange" id="from" value="1" data-modal="calendar_modal">
<input type="text" class="inputs hide date" name="daterange" id="to" value="2" data-modal="calendar_modal">
<input type="text" class="inputs hide txt" name="3" id="txt" value="3">
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('change', '#selectBox', function () {
    $('.inputs').hide();
    $('.'+this.value).show();
});
```

Comment: I want to show both from and to inputs when i click on id - #2

Comment: So the option `1` should hide all fields?

Comment: I have changed my answer, check it now please

Comment: Initial,on select option i want to show last input type (id=3). However, now its not showing any input

Comment: Just remove the class `hide` from the input you want it to appear initially

Comment: I removed it and tried. When i select "Date" option and again when i select "Select" option..then last input type (id=3) is not showing..